# check for app update and download then install it

Tags: android

how can check for app update and download then install it?
i want use retrofit for check version.for example server return this :
json :

```
{
"new_version" : "1.0.1",
"new_change"  : "In new version you can...",
"new_version_url" : "https://test.com/t.apk" 
}
```

in the app only in app start(not onresume,onback,...),compare new version with old and if new version exist,show alert dialog for user and if yes selected,download it and after download run installer.
how can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Get app version :

```
try {
        PackageInfo info=this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(),0);
        String versionName=info.versionName;
        float thisAppVersion=Float.valueOf(versionName);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 if(version_from_net>thisAppVersion(
 showUpdateDialog();
 )
```

Methods for update and show dialog :

```
private void showUpdateDialog(final String url,String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setView(R.layout.update_dialog_layout);
        final AlertDialog dialog=builder.show();
        Button ok,cancel;
        TextView messageText=dialog.findViewById(R.id.update_dialog_message);
        messageText.setText(message);
        ok=dialog.findViewById(R.id.update_dialog_ok_btn);
        cancel=dialog.findViewById(R.id.update_dialog_cancel_btn);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialog.cancel();
                MainActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });
        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                File extFile=getExternalFilesDir(null);
                File tempDir=new File(extFile,"temp");
                File tempApp=new File(tempDir,"temp.apk");
                if (tempApp.exists()){
                    dialog.cancel();
                    APKLauncher launcher=new APKLauncher(MainActivity.this,tempApp);
                    launcher.lunchAPK();
                }else {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    update(url);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void update(String url) {
        ProgressDialog dialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setMessage("downloading ...");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        dialog.setMax(100);

        UpdateApp updateApp=new UpdateApp(this,dialog);
        updateApp.execute(url);

    }
```

UpdateApp class :

```
public class UpdateApp extends AsyncTask<String,String,Void> {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    int status=0;
    private Activity activity;

    public UpdateApp( Activity activity,ProgressDialog progressDialog) {
        this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            int count = 0;
            URL url=new URL(strings[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.connect();
            int lengthOfFile=connection.getContentLength();
            File location = activity.getExternalFilesDir(null);
            File temp=new File(location,"temp");
            if (!temp.exists()){
                temp.mkdir();
            }
            File outputFile=new File(temp,"temp.apk");
            if (outputFile.exists()){
                outputFile.delete();
            }
            FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            InputStream is=connection.getInputStream();
            byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];
            int len=0;
            while ((len=is.read(buffer))!=-1){
                count+=len;
                publishProgress(""+(int)((count*100)/lengthOfFile));
                fos.write(buffer,0,len);
            }
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            is.close();
            APKLauncher launcher=new APKLauncher(activity,outputFile);
            launcher.lunchAPK();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            status=1;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        progressDialog.setProgress(Integer.valueOf(values[0]));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        progressDialog.cancel();
        if (status==1){
            activity.finish();
        }
    }
}
```

APKLuncher class :

```
    public class APKLauncher {
        private Activity activity;
        private File tem

pFile;

    public APKLauncher(Activity activity, File tempFile) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.tempFile = tempFile;
    }
    public void lunchAPK(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.N){
            Uri uri=FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity,BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".provider",tempFile);
            Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("apk"));
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            activity.startActivityForResult(intent, Const.UPDATE_REQUEST_CODE);
        }else {
            Uri uri=Uri.fromFile(tempFile);
            Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("apk"));
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            activity.startActivityForResult(intent, Const.UPDATE_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
        }
    }
```

And for create fileProvider read [this](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en) tutorial :